# UIButton not firing its Target Selector

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIButton that I am placing on a different UIView than the one it is declared in but I want the Target Selector to be in the UIView I declared the button in. The init_button function is getting called because the button is being placed on the view. Here is what I have:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Menu1 : Element {

var color_base = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

var mock : UIView = UIView()
var button : UIButton = UIButton()
var view_width: CGFloat = 0,
    view_height: CGFloat = 0,
    menu_vertical_buffer : CGFloat = 0,
    menu_width : CGFloat = 0,
    button_vertical_buffer : CGFloat = 0,
    button_width : CGFloat = 0


required init(mock: UIView) {
    super.init(mock: mock)
    self.mock = mock
    init_dims()
    init_button()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func init_dims(){
    view_width = mock.frame.width
    view_height = mock.frame.height
    menu_vertical_buffer = CGFloat(floor(Double(view_height/17.5)))
    menu_width = CGFloat(floor(Double(view_width/2.67)))
    button_vertical_buffer = CGFloat(floor(Double(menu_vertical_buffer/3.6)))
    button_width = menu_width - CGFloat(floor(Double(menu_width/7)))
}

func init_button(){
    button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: mock.frame.width - menu_width,
                                    y: mock.frame.height - (menu_vertical_buffer + (2 * button_vertical_buffer)),
                                    width: button_width,
                                    height: menu_vertical_buffer))
    button.backgroundColor = color_base
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.height/2
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeMenuState), for: .touchUpInside)
    mock.addSubview(button)
}

dynamic func changeMenuState(){
    print("Menu state changed")
}




}
```

`changeMenuState` is the function I am adding as the target selector but the button is in the view `mock` not in the view that these functions are in.

Comment: Does `mock` view have `userInteractionEnabled` set to true?

Comment: Yes, I just set mock.isUserInteractionEnabled to true and the same problem occurred.

Comment: Do you receive any error on the console? Try to use use `#selector(Menu1.changeMenuState)` instead

Comment: Check in view hierarchy debugger to see if there are any views on top of your button that are preventing Touch events.

Answer (score 0):

changeMenuState must be dynamic or @objc exposed like

```
@objc func changeMenuState(){
    print("Menu state changed")
}
```

Comment: I added the tag @objc and the tag dynamic and neither of those worked

Comment: Are init_button and changeMenuState in the same class?

Comment: Yes the call to init_button is in the initializer to the class that changeMenuState is in. The only thing outside of the class is the view that the button is added to.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is this might be a scoping issue.  You aren't showing where the button is stored or the lifetime of the scope.  In a typical scenario, you would define a button in a viewcontroller (or perhaps a cell) like so:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var button: UIButton? = nil 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        init_button()
    }
}
```

This way the button stays in scope as long as the view controller is within scope.  Your code looks valid so my "best guess" is the references to button are going out of scope.

You probably need to provide more insight on how these views are working together and the scope of their lifetime (if this comment doesn't help you).

Comment: init_button is called in the initializer for the class, which is a subclass of UIView. There is a separate UIView which I created an instance of and passed as a parameter, now named mock. I don't quite understand the scope of their lifetime or how to find that out.

Comment: The button is added to a view, it doesn't matter in which scope the button is, since it will be kept alive by its superview.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set button's frame corretly? You can set mock's clipsToBounds to YES, then observe.

update：
[image]
As @Badhan Ganesh comment ,you can see the view stack.

Comment: The button is appearing in the view, but upon click the target function is not executing

Comment: Could you provide more code? I can help you find the question.

Comment: Just updated the question to include all of the code for the class. It is a subclass of a class I made called Element which is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: let me know if you need any more. I can provide other classes if you think it would be helpful but the problem seems isolated to this class

Comment: I need your code that you init your mock view . I just set mock frame equal to my view and success.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is correct and I have given the try on same. The issue I found is that your button is appearing on screen but placed out of bound of mock view, hence button is unable to receive the touch event on it. Try to place button inside mock view bounds by setting the frame correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem and it was a scoping issue. I never added the Menu1 class to the mock class or any other view so I believe after it was instantiated and the button placed, that instance was killed so the button was placed but the target was in a class that was no longer in use. what solved my problem was adding `mock.addSubview(self)` to this class.